# "Все силы кинул на ноги или в ноги". Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Все силы кинул на ноги или в ноги". Как правильно сказать?

Comment: Оба предложенных варианта неудачны. Постарайтесь объяснить, какую мысль Вы хотите выразить. Тогда можно будет подумать, как это сделать корректно.

Comment: Есть выражение "бросить все силы на " <цель>". Например, бросить все силы на борьбу за права человека. Но это не вяжется с ногами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно - "в ноги" - как в альтернативный источник энергии, а также в руки как в альтернативное транспортное средство для нее (энергии) для быстрой доставки ее потребителю (сопернику).

Comment: Стёб в ответе контрпродуктивен.

Comment: Трудно признать ответ аргументированным))) Хотя по сути он в чем-то правильный.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве примера:  **Все усилия направил на разработку мышц  ног.**

"Ноги дают больше всего энергии! Эта сила не сравнится ни с чем. Даже самые выдающиеся боксеры имели более разработанные и натренированные ноги, чем руки. http://www.bodyxlife.ru/samyie-boevyie-myishtsyi

Comment: Про ноги, «которые дают»: лучше бы они придавали... Цитировать, так цитировать! Там далее по тексту ещё занятней: «Если внимательно разглядеть (!) тело боксера, знаменитого или нет не важно, можно увидеть, что у них (!) нет перекаченных рук, ног и грудей (!)».

Comment: Ну да,  все силы надо кинуть в ноги (в оригинале всё коротко и ясно). Ну чем не инфостиль М. Ильяхова? Оказывается, сила и энергия нашего организма напрямую зависит от мышц ног. Разве это не ценная информация  и руководство к действию для каждого человеческого индивидуума?

Comment: Ценная информация. Захотелось пойти разглядеть тело индивидуума.